# Getting resultset from insert statement

Tags: java, sql, resultset

i have the below code, where I'm inserting records to a table. When I try to get resultset, it returns null. How to get the latest added row into a resultset?

```
String sql1 = "INSERT INTO [xxxx].[dbo].[xxxxxx](WORKFLOW_SEQ_NBR," +
                      " WORKFLOW_LOG_TYPE_CODE, WORKFLOW_STATUS_CODE, DISP_CODE, DISP_USER, DISP_COMMENT, DISP_TITLE, DISP_TS)" +
                      "VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";
        PreparedStatement pst = connect.prepareStatement(sql1);
        pst.setString(1, ...);
        pst.setString(2, ...);
        ...
        ...
        ...
        pst.executeUpdate();

        ResultSet rstest = pst.executeQuery();
//          ResultSet rstest = pst.getResultSet();
```

EDIT: Resolved

added following method to go to the last added row

```
st.execute("Select * from [xxxx].[dbo].[xxxxxxxxx]");
        ResultSet rstest = st.getResultSet();
        rstest.afterLast();
        GETLASTINSERTED:
        while(rstest.previous()){
            System.out.println(rstest.getObject(1));
            break GETLASTINSERTED;//to read only the last row
        }
```

Comment: What result are you expecting from an insert statement?

Comment: What are you expecting? You have to run a select query to get some results.

Comment: You can't retrieve the result as you expected from `INSERT, UPDATE & DELETE (via executeUpdate())` operations, but can do from `SELECT(FIND) (vis executeQuery())` op.

Comment: I need the row that was inserted using the above pst. How do I move the cursor of the resulset to that row?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

When using a SQL statement such as `INSERT`, `UPDATE` or `DELETE` with a `PreparedStatement`, you must use `executeUpdate`, which will return the number of affeted rows. In this case there is simply no `ResultSet` produced by the sql operation and thus calling executeQuery will throw a `SQLException`.

If you actually need a `ResultSet`  you must make another statement with a `SELECT` SQL operation.

See the javadoc for [PreparedStatement#executeQuery](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#executeQuery) and [PreparedStatement#executeUpdate](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#executeUpdate)

Comment: insert into amalgam_care (id, name, activestatus, incorpcountry, sourcetable, sourcesystem) select fund_id, fund_name, active, domicile, 'EMIS_FUNDS', 'EMIS' from EMIS_FUNDS where status in (2, 3, 4) and active = 1 order by fund_id <- I have this query I want ID to be returned once inserted , how do i do this ?

Answer (score 5):

Seems like this is an older question, but i'm looking for a similar solution, so maybe people will still need this.

If you're doing an insert statement, you can use the :
`Connection.PreparedStatement(String, String[])` constructor, and assign those to a `ResultSet` with `ps.getGeneratedKeys()`.

It would look something like this:

```
public void sqlQuery() {
    PreparedStatement ps = null;
    ResultSet rs = null;
    Connection conn; //Assume this is a properly defined Connection
    String sql = "insert whatever into whatever";
    ps = conn.prepareStatement(sql, new String[]{"example"});
        //do anything else you need to do with the preparedStatement
    ps.execute;
    rs = ps.getGeneratedKeys();
    while(rs.next()){
        //do whatever is needed with the ResultSet
    }
     ps.close();
     rs.close();
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't the example code say `String sql = "insert into..."` instead of `select example`? Anyway, good to know there is a `getGeneratedKeys` method, thanks

Answer (score 1):

[Connection#prepareStatement()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Connection.html#prepareStatement(java.lang.String)) - Creates a `PreparedStatement` object for sending parameterized SQL statements to the database.

which means `connect.prepareStatement(sql1);` created the `PreparedStatement` object using your insert query.

and when you did `pst.executeUpdate();` it will return the row count for SQL Data Manipulation Language (DML) statements or 0 for SQL statements that return nothing

Now if you again want to fetch the data inserted you need to create a new `PreparedStatement` object with `Select` query.

```java
    PreparedStatement pstmt = connect.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM tableName");
```

then this shall give you the `ResultSet` object that contains the data produced by the query

```java
    ResultSet rstest = pstmt.executeQuery();
```