# Insert using PreparedStatement and return values of one column for inserted rows

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, prepared-statement

I'm using `PreparedStatement` to batch insert into a MySQL database. Then I need the query to return the values of one specific column (name) for the successfully inserted rows. I have already tried:

```
preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO x (id,name) VALUES (?,?)", new String[]{"name"});
```

However,  I have not found any method to get the returned values from preparedStatement after it is run. I have tried `preparedStatemet.getGeneratedKeys();` but it only returns the primary key values.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25745094/getting-resultset-from-insert-statement

Comment: @SusanMustafa thanks. but it is not talking about `executeBatch`, it referes to `executeUpdate`

Comment: The `int[]` result (with 0s and 1s) of `executeBatch` might be used to select from an array or List with used names.

Comment: @JoopEggen seems to be the best solution. thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Use the generated keys to find the inserted rows. In that query return any column you desire.

Stay within a single transaction to get unchanging results.

Comment: thanks but it requires at least one additional query!